# MongoDB: Creating a new document field that depends on the values inside another document

Tags: javascript, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I am working with mongo 3.2.6 and I have a collection that contains documents structured as follows:

> db.collection.findOne();

```
{
    "e" : "1",
    "r" : "started",
    "d" : [
        {
            "a" : 1000,
            "t" : 0,
            "ad" : 1000,
            "p" : 102
        },
        {
            "a" : 1290,
            "t" : 0,
            "ad" : 1290,
            "p" : 510
         }
    ],
    "t" : ISODate("2015-11-12T13:21:10.902Z")
}
```

I can happily output the fields of the document to .csv files using mongo export and the aggregation pipeline for the array field `d`. However, I would like to create a new document field known as `t'` (again to be output to .csv files)..and this is where the fun begins...

`t'` is a relative time difference. It takes the time of the current document `t` and subtracts a reference time `t_ref`.

`t_ref` is determined for each event `e` by looking through the current collection to find the first time (for a given event value `e`) that `e = started (and != "not started")`.

So, I want to create a new document field `t' = t - t_ref`
but how can I add a new document field that depends on another document and performs a calculation?

I'm sure this problem has been solved, but I can't find a similar post and I'm really scratching my head!

I'd really appreciate any help :)

Thanks!